# Excel INDEX array return multiple results, combined with IF

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have an list of items with various prices. I have a function that creates an array to show all instances an item occurs:

```
     A       B      C
1 Oranges   10      Yes
2 Apples    12      No
3 Pears     14      Yes
4 Grapes    18      No
5 Apples    19      Yes
6 Oranges   16      No
7 Apples    11      No
```

Using the array

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$7, SMALL(IF($A$10=$A$1:$A$7, ROW($A$1:$A$7)-ROW($A$1)+1), ROW(1:1))), "")}
```

If I type Apple into cell A10, the array will return each instance of apple.

```
12
19
11
```

However I would like to only return each item depending on column C, so return all Apples that are a Yes. I have tried this:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$7, SMALL(IF($A$10=$A$1:$A$7, IF("Yes"=$C$1:$C$7, ROW($A$1:$A$7)-ROW($A$1)+1, ROW(1:1))))), "")}
```

But I keep getting the error I have entered too few arguments for this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$7, SMALL(IF(($A$10=$A$1:$A$7)*("Yes"=$C$1:$C$7), ROW($A$1:$A$7)-ROW($A$1)+1,""), ROW(1:1))), "")`

This works on your data.

Instead of nested IF I've included AND relation, also fixed brackets.